# Not able to calculate y intercept with statsmodels.api for multiple linear regression

Tags: python, linear-regression, data-analysis

My data set for independent variables are as following:

```
>>> reg_data_pd
             a         b         c
0     0.794527  0.033651  0.352414
1     0.794914  0.001086  0.093222
2     0.794476  0.004711  0.027977
3     0.776916  0.035780  0.023156
4     0.773526  0.002273  0.035269
5     0.797933  0.001838  0.131261
6     0.806997  0.011498  0.180022
7     0.780709  0.000766  0.522399
8     0.779954  0.001397  0.036386
9     0.756837  0.010448  0.035893
10    0.775064  0.029471  0.036798
11    0.787213  0.013467  0.081323
12    0.757511  0.016465  0.021611
13    0.794530  0.004141  0.157539
14    0.783696  0.019909  0.021765
15    0.793892  0.003597  0.063312
16    0.762702  0.003547  0.052479
17    0.780336  0.004958  0.084910
18    0.787005  0.006372  0.048153
19    0.824416  0.000513  0.045102
20    0.790552  0.009652  0.581571
21    0.773064  0.000889  0.263941
22    0.772039  0.021499  0.260455
23    0.780298  0.022814  0.061621
24    0.794924  0.020585  0.020638
25    0.772452  0.085798  0.215673
26    0.784202  0.000013  0.233638
27    0.822010  0.082684  0.028724
28    0.772587  0.027979  0.118953
29    0.765530  0.006655  0.018605
...        ...       ...       ...
4771  0.968364  0.227303  0.153739
4772  0.968401  0.159052  0.132388
4773  0.959733  0.278948  0.132163
4774  0.957354  0.315088  0.136973
4775  0.954627  0.447764  0.139494
4776  0.952442  0.305559  0.206204
4777  0.948925  0.235244  0.116273
4778  0.953192  0.228221  0.247231
4779  0.952769  0.327529  0.229617
4780  0.954471  0.396722  0.210942
4781  0.955292  0.336075  0.179493
4782  0.950516  0.320840  0.289505
4783  0.950454  0.316647  0.200065
4784  0.947313  0.291446  0.155215
4785  0.945677  0.292084  0.585302
4786  0.951083  0.285946  0.536361
4787  0.943909  0.346754  0.457234
4788  0.941971  0.276125  0.207159
4789  0.945111  0.440802  0.222561
4790  0.951011  0.407192  0.167613
4791  0.925485  0.464954  0.237568
4792  0.926332  0.252929  0.190035
4793  0.931606  0.020075  0.179730
4794  0.929963  0.426511  0.134418
4795  0.941986  0.640994  0.123444
4796  0.943526  0.232498  0.139800
4797  0.945268  0.460201  0.106471
4798  0.953572  0.398044  0.151489
4799  0.947673  0.479376  0.174330
4800  0.952663  0.532027  0.409197

[4801 rows x 3 columns]
```

And the data set for dependent variable is:

```
>>> yu_pd
             y
0     0.290740
1     0.295920
2     0.295920
3     0.192100
4     0.266000
5     0.284700
6     0.284700
7     0.272300
8     0.282680
9     0.243260
10    0.243260
11    0.273150
12    0.273150
13    0.282850
14    0.300325
15    0.192525
16    0.192525
17    0.269620
18    0.286825
19    0.207700
20    0.207700
21    0.292380
22    0.292380
23    0.282600
24    0.278212
25    0.243512
26    0.243512
27    0.309025
28    0.361740
29    0.249520
...        ...
4771  0.251480
4772  0.287500
4773  0.287500
4774  0.282071
4775  0.313343
4776  0.287463
4777  0.287463
4778  0.298700
4779  0.272920
4780  0.272920
4781  0.371314
4782  0.388429
4783  0.305200
4784  0.305200
4785  0.296725
4786  0.287920
4787  0.271580
4788  0.305486
4789  0.318571
4790  0.337975
4791  0.337975
4792  0.319988
4793  0.192360
4794  0.312871
4795  0.323000
4796  0.347088
4797  0.347088
4798  0.324986
4799  0.184320
4800  0.352100

[4801 rows x 1 columns]
```

My code for calculating multiple line regression is as following:

```
>>> import statsmodels.api as sm
>>> model = sm.OLS(yu_pd,reg_data_pd)
>>> results = model.fit()
>>> results.summary()
<class 'statsmodels.iolib.summary.Summary'>
"""
                            OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      y   R-squared:                       0.896
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  0.896
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                 1.379e+04
Date:                Thu, 28 Jan 2016   Prob (F-statistic):               0.00
Time:                        16:45:03   Log-Likelihood:                 6693.6
No. Observations:                4801   AIC:                        -1.338e+04
Df Residuals:                    4798   BIC:                        -1.336e+04
Df Model:                           3                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [95.0% Conf. Int.]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
a              0.1933      0.002     78.058      0.000         0.188     0.198
b              0.0135      0.005      2.796      0.005         0.004     0.023
c             -0.0221      0.006     -3.984      0.000        -0.033    -0.011
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                      151.028   Durbin-Watson:                   0.452
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.000   Jarque-Bera (JB):              166.568
Skew:                           0.430   Prob(JB):                     6.77e-37
Kurtosis:                       3.306   Cond. No.                         6.75
==============================================================================

Warnings:
[1] Standard Errors assume that the covariance matrix of the errors is correctly specified.
"""
```

I have got all the coefficients 'a', 'b' and 'c' but I did not get the value of my Y intercept.

Comment: If you use the array/dataframe interface, then the array of explanatory variables is not changed by the model, for example an intercept is not added. If you don't add an intercept (column of ones) yourself then it is a regression through the origin. The patsy formula handling, and consequently the formula interface to the model, adds an intercept by default.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a regression model with 3 independent variables, why do you expect there to be a unique definition of the Y-intercept in your datasummary? I think this is a notion that applies when there is a single function of a single independent variable.

Consider the following:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import random
import statsmodels.api as sm

x = np.linspace(0,1,100)
X = 0.45*x
X1 = 0.45*x
x3 = np.zeros(200).reshape((100,2))
x3[:,0] = X[:]
x3[:,1] = X1[:]

y = 0.45*x

model = sm.OLS(y, x3)
results = model.fit()
print(results.summary())
                            OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      y   R-squared:                         1.000
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  1.000
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                 5.710e+33
Date:                Thu, 28 Jan 2016   Prob (F-statistic):               0.00
Time:                        15:11:53   Log-Likelihood:                 3649.3
No. Observations:                 100   AIC:                            -7297.
Df Residuals:                      99   BIC:                            -7294.
Df Model:                           1                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
             coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [95.0% Conf. Int.]
x1             0.5000   6.62e-18   7.56e+16      0.000         0.500     0.500
x2             0.5000   6.62e-18   7.56e+16      0.000         0.500     0.500
```

Now this is telling me my coefficients are indeed the slopes of two lines. So in your case, the values a, b, and c are the slopes of the three lines for the independent variable input, matching the Y-variable output.

If any of these lines had a Y-intercept, say Y = a0 + a*x, where x is the independent variable, you could solve for the slope by setting x and Y equal to values obtained from the deta; for example, if the point x =  Y = 1 appears in the same row, then set x = Y = 1, to get the Y-int: a0 = 1-a. You could do the same for the other two lines you fit. I believe this is now a complete answer to your question.

Comment: I have three independent variables as I have specified in my question

Comment: Typo I meant independent! Fixed my post. Sorry :)

Comment: I am new to multi linear regression, please help me understand some basics, I am aware of the fact that having 3 independent variables will result in 3 lines. y = a + x1a1 + x2a2 + x3a3 will be the equation, where a1, a2, a3 are my slopes. Now to calculate y in need the value of one more variable, i:e 'a'. Even I do not know which line slope (a1,a2,a3) will cause the y intercept. Can you clarify what is the line which is causing the y intercept.

Comment: @chickenjoe I did a bit of numerical experimentation to be sure what your output values for a, b and c really meant. I'm quite sure the complete explanation is now given in my answer.